# Saving Values in STM32f769i Disco Board

Tags: memory, save, eeprom, stm32f7

I have an stm32f769i disco board and have developed a screen that has a series of timers and other values that get changed periodically. Is there a way to save these values in the board with a simple save icon?

Tried saving to memory card with no luck